# How to append on time and append into span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

In this code I tried to append title into span with unique id. This AJAX calling will return username and append it to specific span with specific id only one time, so if I hover again it is supposed not to work.

Right now it's working good with AJAX calling but it still runs every time I hover. Another problem it appends after the span not into the span. How to solve it?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#16").hover(function(e){
            var val = 16;
            $.ajax({
                'type': 'get',
                'url': 'tree/get_parent_ajax/'+ val,
                'dataType': 'json',
                'success': function (data) {
                    $("span#"+val).append("title= '" + data + "'");
                    alert(data);
                }
            }, function(){
                e.stopPropagation();
                //This function is for unhover.
            });

        });
    });

</script>


<a href="http://localhost/ammar/users/cv/16" class="color-white" target="_blank">
                <span id="16" class="first_name">الجد راشدtitle= ' الجد راشد  عبدالرحمن بن عمار آل محمد 'title= ' الجد راشد  عبدالرحمن بن عمار آل محمد 'title= ' الجد راشد  عبدالرحمن بن عمار آل محمد 'title= ' الجد راشد  عبدالرحمن بن عمار آل محمد 'title= ' الجد راشد  عبدالرحمن بن عمار آل محمد 'title= ' الجد راشد  عبدالرحمن بن عمار آل محمد '</span>
                </a>
```

Comment: Can you show the full code or  a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a counter to get the first hover or another:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#16").hover(function(e){
        var val = 16;
        if(counter==0){
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'get',
            'url': 'tree/get_parent_ajax/'+ val,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': function (data) {
                $("span#"+val).attr("title= '" + data + "'");
                counter = counter + 1;
                alert(data);
            }
        }, function(){
            e.stopPropagation();
            //This function is for unhover.
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Counter will be 0 on page load (and will execute the ajax call). When the ajax is successful it will become 1 and then the hover will no longer trigger ajax unless you reload the page.
I also fixed the point about the title. You need to use .attr() to change an attribute of an html element. .append will be used to add text inside the html tag. So it will be used if you want to add some text inside the span that will be visible on the page

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get what exactly you want but you could check if the span already contains data.Ex:

```
$("#16").hover(function(e){

        $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); //detach event listeners
       if($(this).html()!="")
       {
       var val = 16;
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'get',
            'url': 'tree/get_parent_ajax/'+ val,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': function (data) {
                $("#"+val).html('');   
                $("span#"+val).append("title= '" + data + "'");
                alert(data);
            }
         );
        }, function(){
            e.stopPropagation();
            //This function is for unhover.


    });
```

And also on ajax success just empty old values of span and add newly recieved values.